# Simple mechanics question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

A beaker filled with water is placed on the scale.
A weight denser than water is tied to one end of a string; the other end of the string is tied to a stick. The weight is then placed in water with the stick supported over the rim of the beaker. Total weight at this time is recorded.
If the string is suddenly cut and the weight sinks at a constant velocity, will the reading of the scale change?
*Assuming stick and string are massless*

My reasoning is that
1)at initial condition, net force of stick on the beaker is equal to the weight of the weight minus the buoyant force applied by the water to the weight, which is the tension force in the string. The recorded weight should be equal to mass of beaker + water + net force of stick on beaker.
 2)when string is cut, as it sinks at constant velocity Fnet=0 for the weight. Thus the weight is "canceled out" by the buoyant force and net forced applied by stick on the beaker is 0. I suspect that the final reading will be less, but I could not be sure.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

[image: diagram]

Comment: Any diagrams you could add for clarification? Think about the masses involved in the system. Draw a before and after diagram. Think about if the total mass on top of the scale different after the string is cut.

Comment: Added. Pls let me know if there is anything unclear. Thanks for the help! The total mass does not change; water does not overflow. *Assuming both string and stick are massless.

Comment: You should either 1) tell us your answer with your physics reasoning and ask a pertinent conceptual question which will lead to a final answer or 2) do the experiment and report what you see, with an explanation of why it makes sense or not.   Don't expect us to give you an answer to the question in your post.

Comment: Hello Bill N, my reasoning is that 1)at initial condition, net force of stick on the beaker is equal to the weight of the weight minus the buoyant force applied by the water to the weight, which is the tension force in the string.  The recorded weight should be equal to mass of beaker + water + net force of stick on beaker.  2)when string is cut, as it sinks at constant velocity Fnet=0 for the weight. Thus the weight is "canceled out" by the buoyant force and net forced applied by stick on the beaker is 0. I suspect that the final reading will be less, but I could not be sure. Thanks.

Comment: Do not use the comments to provide clarifying information. Edit the question-that's where the important information should be. You can use the comments to state you have edited the question.

Comment: And have you read the "Help" and "Tour" links at the bottom. They give a lot of information about good and bad questions (and answers).

Comment: Details added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is that the mass of the ball is cancelled out by the bouyancy of the water once the string is cut, but you need to think about this carefully.

To prompt you in the right direction consider a similar situation: you are standing on a large set of scales. Next to you and also on the scales is a cannonball. Let's say that your mass is 60kg and the cannonball's mass is 10kg, so the scale reads 70kg. Now you pick the cannonball up and hold it in your hands. What do you think the scales will read then? This situation is similar because when you are holding the cannonball the force from your hands is cancelling out the weight of the cannonball. Much like you argue the water is doing to the weight in the question.

Comment: So what you are saying is that, despite the various forces acting on the weight before and after the string is cut, as long as the total mass does not change and the scale and beaker remains stationary, the reading on the scale will not change?

Comment: @TonyWang, Ollie is wanting you to keep Newton's 3rd law in mind.  For any forces involved, there are equal magnitude forces which act in the opposite direction.  What does this imply for your problem?